# Flutter Custom Notification sound not working (FCM)

Tags: laravel, firebase, flutter

my notification sound not play as expected, i want it to change the sound with .mp3 file, i've done put the mp3 file to raw/res but it still not working properly

```
{
  title: dape, Lorem Ipsum 1, 
  body: Klik untuk menerima layanan.
}, 
  data: {
    type_order: one day,
    payment_method: cash, 
    payment: 10000, 
    fee: 3000, 
    click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK,
}
```

[image]

i have no idea what happened

Comment: Is the phone on silent?

Comment: no the phone isn't silent.. but the sound always showed up as default @S.Ramjit